# Django: django-secretballot MIDDLEWARE

Tags: django, package, django-middleware

When adding  `'secretballot.middleware.SecretBallotMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` I keep getting the following error:

`Exception Type: NotImplementedError`

`Exception Location: .../django_secretballot-0.2.3-py2.7.egg/secretballot/middleware.py in generate_token, line 11`

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot#tokens-and-secretballotmiddleware), you shouldn't add `secretballot.middleware.SecretBallotMiddleware` middleware.

Choose from `SecretBallotIpMiddleware` or `SecretBallotIpUseragentMiddleware`.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm brand new to all this. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this error is that SecretBallotMiddleware is actually an abstract class ([source](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot/blob/master/secretballot/middleware.py)) you need to subclass it or use already implemented SecretBallotIpMiddleware. See documentation section [MIDDLEWARE](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-secretballot#tokens-and-secretballotmiddleware) for details.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm new to all this. I appreciate the insight.